# Fourier-type series representation of "quasi-periodic" functions

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, analytic-number-theory

By a quasi-$T$-periodic function on some set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, I mean a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x) = f(x + T) + o(1)$ for all $x \in S$, where $o(1)$ denotes a quantity that tends to zero as $x \to \infty$. For example, the function $\log(x)$ is quasi-1-periodic for $x$ large enough, since $\log(x + 1) = \log(x) + O(1/x)$ for $x > 1$. Thus as $x$ grows large, $\log(x)$ behaves more and more like a $1$-periodic function. I am wondering if there's a theory of Fourier-type series representation for such functions. For example, given a quasi-$T$-periodic function $f$ satisfying $f(x + T) = f(x) + O(1/x)$, can we find a representation of the form 
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{2\pi i (n + \epsilon(n))x/T}
$$
for $f(x)$ converging almost everywhere, where the real numbers $\epsilon(n)$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, vanish at infinity? Thanks.

Comment: There are some results for ['almost periodic functions'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function). You may have a look into the book 'Almost Periodic Functions and Differential Equations' by Levitan and Zhikov.

Comment: The logarithm is also $\sqrt{2}$- quasi-periodic and $\pi$-quasiperiodic; what T would you expect to see in the  series?

Comment: Yes, it is quasi-T-periodic for any bounded $T$. I don't know what $T$ should be expected since I don't even know if such representations are possible